# Image Optimization: Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I need an expert advise which one of the Grunt plugin is much more effective in image optimization.
Is it grunt-tinyimg or grunt-contrib-imagemin? or Is there something better?
Thank you